# Should I prefer to use specifically-sized Int (Int8 and Int16) in Swift?

Tags: swift, types

I'm converting projects from Java to Swift. My Java code uses small data types (`short`, `byte`). Should I use the `Int16`, `Int8` equivalents in Swift, or only use the `Int` type for all? Where is the memory optimization as well as the speed?

Comment: Even if in Java you should use `int` if there is no specific reason to do otherwise. Note that many Java arithmetic operations automatically promote to `int`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Double and Int unless compelled by circumstances to do otherwise. The other types are all for compatibility with externalities.

For example, you have to use CGFloat to interchange with Core Graphics, and an occasional UIKit object requires a Float instead of a Double; and you might have to use Int8 for purposes of interchange with some C API or to deal with data downloaded from the network.

But Double and Int are the "natural" Swift types, and Swift numerics are very rigid and clumsy, so you should stick with those types wherever you can.

Comment: One more reason to use Int is that it uses Int32 on 32-bits OS and uses Int64 on 64-bits OS.